# Display images as Thumbnail

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to display my uploaded images as a thumbnail in my template . I have installed the sorl-thumbnail in my installed app . when i am executing my application i am getting a template error like this :

> Syntax error. Expected: `thumbnail source geometry [key1=val1 key2=val2...] as var`
>   Exception Location:   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sorl_thumbnail-11.12 py2.7.egg/sorl/thumbnail/templatetags/thumbnail.py in **init**, line 65

please help me to find the solution . my codes are as follows

```
class Photo(models.Model):
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/home/forent/sites1/dreamaddress/media/uploads/properties/image')
   tag=models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True,blank=True)
   caption=models.CharField(max_length=755, null=True,blank=True)
   prop=models.ForeignKey(Property,blank=True,null=True)
```

View :

```
def img_all(request):
    imgs = Photo.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('details.html',{'imgs':imgs},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

settings.py

```
# Django settings for dreamaddress project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'properties.UserProfile'

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'dreamaddress',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT ='/home/forent/sites1/dreamaddress/media/'




# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/forent/sites1/dreamaddress/sitestatic/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/sitestatic/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/home/forent/sites1/dreamaddress/properties/static/',
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'gl=@6g+m6yw_j8-ybqme0-3w+iz81ib185twqh9-l%m32a6=_j'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dreamaddress.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/home/forent/sites1/dreamaddress/template/'
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'properties',
    'south',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

details.html :

```
    {% load thumbnail %}
                        <div>

                                 {% for img in imgs %}
                    <div class="slide">
                        <a href="#"><li><img src="{% thumbnail img.image 480x312 crop,sharpen,quality=90 %}" alt=""></li></a>
                <div class="caption" style="bottom:0">
                <p>{{ img.caption }}</p>
                </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Look at the example in the docs](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/template.html#thumbnail)

You need to quote your geometry values:

```
<img src="{% thumbnail img.image '480x312' crop="center" quality="90" %}" alt="">
```

Comment: Have you actually provided values to the options? I've edited the answer to show you